# Creating a file in a folder picked by UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, file, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am trying to create multiple files in a folder picked by user using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` with `UTType.Folder`.

I am able to create subfolders by appending to the `NSUrl` and using `NSFileManager` `createDirectoryAtURL`, but there is no `createFileAtURL` method, only `createFileAtPath`. This should work for local files, but is there a general way to create a file in any picked location, even if it were a third-party cloud provider?

Comment: What does "create" mean here? You can create a file at a given URL just by starting with some Data and telling it to `write` to that URL. You don't need a file manager method to do that.

Comment: I am looking for something like "touch" on Unix. Basically, want to be able to create an empty file, which could later be either written to, or not.